# RabbitMQ Plugins I can't get to the steps described?

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV6Ts.png)
I can't get to the steps described,
I installed Erlang and RabbitMQ Server using the official RabbitMQ installation,
When I enabled Manegement Times error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFqGJ.png)
And I turned on the firewall on ports 5672 and 15672

Comment: rabbitmq-service said kernel pid terminated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: run  rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management have error like picture show